# How to add static files/resources to Android Application

Tags: android, android-assets

Android supports Assets and I can put files in Assets and copy them from Java code to actual file system.

However I have a static database of around 100MB that I need to have as physical files that are accessed via some library and I can't change the API to accessing Assets.

I wonder if there is any way to have app files put into physical file system outside Asset system to save scares disk space.

Comment: can you not store the the db inside the `sdcard` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need it on the file system and not assets, you have two options:

1)Add it to assets anyway, then copy it on first launch to the filesystem.  Pro of this is it's simple, the con is that it wastes disk space.

2)Download it from the net on first launch.  The pro of this is not waster disk space, the con is that it requires network access and your file is going to be publicly accessible on the web.  Although it's not like it's hard to get it from disk anyway if someone wanted it.

There's a few niche solutions like expansion apks, but that's really just a variation on 2 with the play store serving as the web host.

Comment: Thanks. I thought of 2nd option as well - and thank for confirming what I was thinking of.